# Struts2 conversion of list to integer or double not working

Tags: java, struts2

I am new to Struts2 and learn it using Struts2 in action. I found an example in the book which maps request parameter to a list and at the same time it try to convert the parameters from default type string into double or integer. It assumes that the list has no type info (as prior to java 5). I am getting exception.

**Login.jsp**

```
 <s:form  action="LoginAction">
    <s:textfield name="username" label="Username"></s:textfield>
    <s:password name="password" label="Password"></s:password>
    <s:textfield name="age" label="Age"></s:textfield>
    <s:textfield name="name" label="First Name"></s:textfield>
    <s:textfield name="name" label="Second Name"></s:textfield>
    <s:textfield name="name" label="Last Name"></s:textfield>
    <s:submit value="Login"></s:submit>
</s:form>
```

**LoginAction**

```
package org.shammu.actions;

import java.util.List;

import com.opensymphony.xwork2.ActionSupport;

@SuppressWarnings("serial")
public class LoginAction extends ActionSupport{

private String username;
private String password;
private int age;
private List name;
public String getUsername() {
    return username;
}
public void setUsername(String username) {
    this.username = username;
}
public String getPassword() {
    return password;
}
public void setPassword(String password) {
    this.password = password;
}
public List getName() {
    return name;
}
public void setName(List name) {
    this.name = name;
}
public int getAge() {
    return age;
}
public void setAge(int age) {
    this.age = age;
}
```

}

**Stacktrace**

```
Sep 3, 2013 11:06:22 AM      
com.opensymphony.xwork2.conversion.impl.DefaultConversionFileProcessor error
SEVERE: Problem loading properties for org.shammu.actions.LoginAction
java.lang.InstantiationException: java.lang.Double
at java.lang.Class.newInstance0(Unknown Source)
at java.lang.Class.newInstance(Unknown Source)
at com.opensymphony.xwork2.ObjectFactory.buildBean(ObjectFactory.java:131)
at com.opensymphony.xwork2.ObjectFactory.buildBean(ObjectFactory.java:162)
at com.opensymphony.xwork2.ObjectFactory.buildBean(ObjectFactory.java:151)
at com.opensymphony.xwork2.conversion.impl.DefaultTypeConverterCreator.
       createTypeConverter(DefaultTypeConverterCreator.java:23)
at com.opensymphony.xwork2.conversion.impl.DefaultConversionFileProcessor.
       process(DefaultConversionFileProcessor.java:68)
at com.opensymphony.xwork2.conversion.impl.XWorkConverter.addConverterMapping
       (XWorkConverter.java:485)
at com.opensymphony.xwork2.conversion.impl.XWorkConverter.buildConverterMapping
       (XWorkConverter.java:549)
at com.opensymphony.xwork2.conversion.impl.XWorkConverter.getConverter
       (XWorkConverter.java:417)
at com.opensymphony.xwork2.conversion.impl.XWorkConverter.convertValue
       (XWorkConverter.java:282)
at com.opensymphony.xwork2.ognl.OgnlTypeConverterWrapper.convertValue
       (OgnlTypeConverterWrapper.java:39)
at ognl.OgnlRuntime.getConvertedType(OgnlRuntime.java:1080)
at ognl.OgnlRuntime.getConvertedTypes(OgnlRuntime.java:1097)
at ognl.OgnlRuntime.getConvertedMethodAndArgs(OgnlRuntime.java:1123)
at ognl.OgnlRuntime.getAppropriateMethod(OgnlRuntime.java:1209)
at ognl.OgnlRuntime.callAppropriateMethod(OgnlRuntime.java:1223)
at ognl.OgnlRuntime.setMethodValue(OgnlRuntime.java:1494)
at ognl.ObjectPropertyAccessor.setPossibleProperty(ObjectPropertyAccessor.java:85)
at ognl.ObjectPropertyAccessor.setProperty(ObjectPropertyAccessor.java:162)
at com.opensymphony.xwork2.ognl.accessor.ObjectAccessor.setProperty
       (ObjectAccessor.java:27)
at ognl.OgnlRuntime.setProperty(OgnlRuntime.java:2332)
at com.opensymphony.xwork2.ognl.accessor.CompoundRootAccessor.setProperty
       (CompoundRootAccessor.java:78)
at ognl.OgnlRuntime.setProperty(OgnlRuntime.java:2332)
at ognl.ASTProperty.setValueBody(ASTProperty.java:127)
at ognl.SimpleNode.evaluateSetValueBody(SimpleNode.java:220)
at ognl.SimpleNode.setValue(SimpleNode.java:301)
at ognl.Ognl.setValue(Ognl.java:737)
at com.opensymphony.xwork2.ognl.OgnlUtil.setValue(OgnlUtil.java:234)
at com.opensymphony.xwork2.ognl.OgnlValueStack.trySetValue(OgnlValueStack.java:183)
at com.opensymphony.xwork2.ognl.OgnlValueStack.setValue(OgnlValueStack.java:170)
at com.opensymphony.xwork2.ognl.OgnlValueStack.setParameter 
       (OgnlValueStack.java:148)
at com.opensymphony.xwork2.interceptor.ParametersInterceptor.setParameters
       (ParametersInterceptor.java:318)
at com.opensymphony.xwork2.interceptor.ParametersInterceptor.doIntercept
       (ParametersInterceptor.java:231)
at com.opensymphony.xwork2.interceptor.MethodFilterInterceptor.intercept
       (MethodFilterInterceptor.java:98)
at com.opensymphony.xwork2.DefaultActionInvocation.invoke
       (DefaultActionInvocation.java:246)
at com.opensymphony.xwork2.interceptor.ParametersInterceptor.doIntercept
       (ParametersInterceptor.java:239)
at com.opensymphony.xwork2.interceptor.MethodFilterInterceptor.intercept
       (MethodFilterInterceptor.java:98)
at com.opensymphony.xwork2.DefaultActionInvocation.invoke
       (DefaultActionInvocation.java:246)
at com.opensymphony.xwork2.interceptor.StaticParametersInterceptor.intercept
       (StaticParametersInterceptor.java:191)
at com.opensymphony.xwork2.DefaultActionInvocation.invoke
       (DefaultActionInvocation.java:246)
at org.apache.struts2.interceptor.MultiselectInterceptor.intercept
        (MultiselectInterceptor.java:73)
at com.opensymphony.xwork2.DefaultActionInvocation.invoke
       (DefaultActionInvocation.java:246)
at org.apache.struts2.interceptor.CheckboxInterceptor.intercept
       (CheckboxInterceptor.java:91)
at com.opensymphony.xwork2.DefaultActionInvocation.invoke
       (DefaultActionInvocation.java:246)
at org.apache.struts2.interceptor.FileUploadInterceptor.intercept
       (FileUploadInterceptor.java:252)
at com.opensymphony.xwork2.DefaultActionInvocation.invoke
       (DefaultActionInvocation.java:246)
at com.opensymphony.xwork2.interceptor.ModelDrivenInterceptor.intercept
       (ModelDrivenInterceptor.java:100)
at com.opensymphony.xwork2.DefaultActionInvocation.invoke
       (DefaultActionInvocation.java:246)
at com.opensymphony.xwork2.interceptor.ScopedModelDrivenInterceptor.intercept
       (ScopedModelDrivenInterceptor.java:141)
at com.opensymphony.xwork2.DefaultActionInvocation.invoke
       (DefaultActionInvocation.java:246)
at com.opensymphony.xwork2.interceptor.ChainingInterceptor.intercept
       (ChainingInterceptor.java:145)
at com.opensymphony.xwork2.DefaultActionInvocation.invoke
      (DefaultActionInvocation.java:246)
at com.opensymphony.xwork2.interceptor.PrepareInterceptor.doIntercept
      (PrepareInterceptor.java:171)
at com.opensymphony.xwork2.interceptor.MethodFilterInterceptor.intercept
      (MethodFilterInterceptor.java:98)
at com.opensymphony.xwork2.DefaultActionInvocation.invoke
      (DefaultActionInvocation.java:246)
at com.opensymphony.xwork2.interceptor.I18nInterceptor.intercept
      (I18nInterceptor.java:161)
at com.opensymphony.xwork2.DefaultActionInvocation.invoke
      (DefaultActionInvocation.java:246)
at org.apache.struts2.interceptor.ServletConfigInterceptor.intercept
      (ServletConfigInterceptor.java:164)
at com.opensymphony.xwork2.DefaultActionInvocation.invoke
      (DefaultActionInvocation.java:246)
at com.opensymphony.xwork2.interceptor.AliasInterceptor.intercept
     (AliasInterceptor.java:193)
at com.opensymphony.xwork2.DefaultActionInvocation.invoke
      (DefaultActionInvocation.java:246)
at com.opensymphony.xwork2.interceptor.ExceptionMappingInterceptor.intercept
     (ExceptionMappingInterceptor.java:189)
at com.opensymphony.xwork2.DefaultActionInvocation.invoke
       (DefaultActionInvocation.java:246)
at org.apache.struts2.impl.StrutsActionProxy.execute(StrutsActionProxy.java:54)
at org.apache.struts2.dispatcher.Dispatcher.serviceAction(Dispatcher.java:563)
at org.apache.struts2.dispatcher.ng.ExecuteOperations.executeAction
    (ExecuteOperations.java:77)
at org.apache.struts2.dispatcher.ng.filter.StrutsPrepareAndExecuteFilter.doFilter
    (StrutsPrepareAndExecuteFilter.java:99)
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter
    (ApplicationFilterChain.java:243)
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter
     (ApplicationFilterChain.java:210)
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke
     (StandardWrapperValve.java:222)
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke
    (StandardContextValve.java:123)
at org.apache.catalina.authenticator.AuthenticatorBase.invoke
    (AuthenticatorBase.java:472)
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:171)
at org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:99)
at org.apache.catalina.valves.AccessLogValve.invoke(AccessLogValve.java:953)
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke
    (StandardEngineValve.java:118)
at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service
    (CoyoteAdapter.java:408)
at org.apache.coyote.http11.AbstractHttp11Processor.process
    (AbstractHttp11Processor.java:1023)
at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol$AbstractConnectionHandler.process
       (AbstractProtocol.java:589)
at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.JIoEndpoint$SocketProcessor.run(JIoEndpoint.java:312)
at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.runTask(Unknown Source)
at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(Unknown Source)
at java.lang.Thread.run(Unknown Source)
```

Here my conversion file placed in the same folder of action class is **LoginAction-conversion.properties** has a single line `Element-name=java.lang.Double`.
Help me

Comment: Why would you specify that `name` is a `Double`? That makes no sense and is the source of your exception.

Comment: @Jim Garrison. I know it works fine with List<Double> name; But according to that book(Struts2 in action), if we use java 4 or less, we can specify this using the property file. As a leaner, actually I want to know why this exception.

Comment: @Shameer Your conversions doesn't work due to the syntax error.

Answer (score 2):

This should be as `Element_name=java.lang.Double` .

Answer (score 0):

In your `LoginAction-conversion.properties` file you do not actually tell what the resulting type needs to be but what converter must be used.  The easiest way to create a converter to extend the following class:
`org.apache.struts2.util.StrutsTypeConverter`

You have to provide an implementation for the following methods:
`convertFromString`
`convertToString`

And in your property file you would have something like

age=`<<your extension of org.apache.struts2.util.StrutsTypeConverter>>`

Your should also check the following guide: [Struts 2.3.x TypeConversion](http://struts.apache.org/release/2.3.x/docs/type-conversion.html)